# Javascript Array empties after redefining variable to contain new full array then setting a specific index to another value

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

I have a variable currentQL which is set to an empty array. This array is then set to contain 6 string values, however, when I then do currentQL[0] the array then only contains that one value.

```
  currentQLs = [];
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['quickLinks'], function(result) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.error && result.quickLinks != undefined) {
        currentQLs = result.quickLinks;
    } else if (result.quickLinks == undefined) {
        currentQLs = ["https://youtube.com", "https://facebook.com", "https://yahoo.com", "https://smile.amazon.com", "https://twitter.com", "https://gmail.com"];
    }
  });
  currentQLs[qlNum - 1] = qlURL;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({quickLinks: currentQLs}, function() {
    console.log("Saved URL");
  });
}
```

I expected something like ["https://google.com", "https://facebook.com", "https://yahoo.com", "https://smile.amazon.com", "https://twitter.com", "https://gmail.com"], when I do saveQLs(1, "https://google.com").

I'm sure it's probably something very simple I'm missing, but thanks in advance!

Comment: Chrome API have callbacks not just because it's fancy, but because they are invoked asynchronously, meaning the code inside runs after the outer code. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321) or maybe look for a tutorial on asynchronous JS.

Comment: It's just because you're outside the callback, so `curentQLs` is not modified yet.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! I thought it was something dumb like that. )